# Log contextual data (without specifying it explicitly)

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a multi-tenant app where I need to log a lot more data than what I pass to the log facade. What I mean is, every time I do this...

```
Log::info('something happened');
```

I get this:

> [2017-02-15 18:12:55] local.INFO: something happened

But I want to get this:

> [2017-02-15 18:12:55] [my ec2 instance id] [client_id] local.INFO: something happened

As you can see I'm logging the EC2 instance ID and my app's client ID. I'm of course simplifying this as I need to log a lot more stuff in there. When I consume and aggregate these logs, having these extra fields make them incredibly handy to figure what things went wrong and where.

In the Zend Framework, I usually subclass the logger and add these extra fields in my subclass but I'm not sure how I can do that with Laravel. I can't find where the logger is instantiated so that I can plug my custom logger in (if that is even the way to go in Laravel).

So, I'm not asking how to get the EC2 instance ID and the other stuff, I'm only asking what the proper way to "hot wire" the Laravel logger is to be able to plug this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea... the logger in Laravel is really a Monolog instance... You could push a handler on it and do whatever processing you want for each entry... like so...

```
<?php

$logger->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
    $record['extra']['dummy'] = 'Hello world!';

    return $record;
});
```

As per the Laravel doc you can hook up into the monolog config at boot...

> Custom Monolog Configuration
>
> If you would like to have complete control over how Monolog is
>   configured for your application, you may use the application's
>   configureMonologUsing method. You should place a call to this method
>   in your bootstrap/app.php file right before the $app variable is
>   returned by the file:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(...);
});

return $app;
```

So instead just push a processor on the $monolog instance passed to the hook...

Just an idea, I have not tried this in Laravel but used Monolog before...